flask-sqlalchemy multiple join conditions in relationship
I have a simple linkage of foreign keys in part of my database schema, and I would like to use a relationship to access all linked rows. Here is a stripped down version of my problem:
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask

db: SQLAlchemy = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database_name.db'
db.init_app(app)


class Child(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("Parent.id"))
    parent = db.relationship("Parent")
    
class ToyShare(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("child.id"), nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Float)

class Parent(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    toy_shares = db.relationship(
        "ToyShare",
        primaryjoin="Child.parent_id == Parent.id",
    )


However, when I try to use the the toy_shares attribute in any way, I get
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any simple equality expressions involving locally mapped foreign key columns for primary join condition 'child.parent_id = parent.id' on relationship Parent.toy_shares.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation. To allow comparison operators other than '==', the relationship can be marked as viewonly=True.

I attempted a few things like foreign_keys=[Child.parent_id, ToyShare.child_id] and a secondaryjoin, but couldn't get the relationship right. The error message is confusing to me, since the foreign keys linking Parent and ToyShare look so simple.
Is relationship the wrong approach here, or can it be made to work?

This looks like two 1-to-many relationships.  I don't think you could use a regular relationship for this because it couldn't be used to correctly persist to the database, espeically if Child has additional columns.  You could add a viewonly relationship but I'm not sure if it would be worth it.  It has similar problems to trying to skip the secondary table/class in a many-to-many relationship, discussed in this section association-object.
Why can't you just use the regular relationships to access the ToyShare objects? select(ToyShare).join(ToyShare.child).join(Child.parent)?
class Child(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'childs'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    parent = db.relationship("Parent", back_populates="childs")
    toy_shares = db.relationship(
        "ToyShare", back_populates="child"
    )

class ToyShare(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'toy_shares'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("childs.id"), nullable=False)
    time = db.Column(db.Float)
    child = db.relationship(
        "Child", back_populates="toy_shares"
    )

class Parent(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    childs = db.relationship(
        "Child", back_populates="parent"
    )
    # Shorthand relationship to get the toyshares of this parent's children.
    toy_shares = relationship("ToyShare",
        secondary="childs", viewonly=True
    )

